# Gerrit git clone bad address:29418

Tags: git, gerrit, ssh-keys

I met a problem when I did git clone operation from my private Gerrit repository, the Gerrit server responded me the following errors:

```
$ git clone -v ssh://user@localhost:29418/sample-project
Cloning into 'sample-project'...
ssh: connect to host localhost port 29418: Bad address
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, I could still perform the command `git review` correctly. Here was my execution history:

```
user@user-PC MINGW64 ~
$ ssh -p 29418 -v user@localhost gerrit
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to localhost [localhost] port 29418.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version GerritCodeReview_2.11 (SSHD-CORE-0.14.0)
debug1: no match: GerritCodeReview_2.11 (SSHD-CORE-0.14.0)
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:29418 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:Rk2to0JI8M57vEwLrH3dHQhw+B/s0fdERul+y93s37c
debug1: Host '[localhost]:29418' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to localhost ([localhost]:29418).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending command: gerrit
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Available commands of gerrit are:

   apropos              Search in Gerrit documentation
   ban-commit           Ban a commit from a project's repository
   close-connection     Close the specified SSH connection
   create-account       Create a new batch/role account
   create-branch        Create a new branch
   create-group         Create a new account group
   create-project       Create a new project and associated Git repository
   flush-caches         Flush some/all server caches from memory
   gc                   Run Git garbage collection
   gsql                 Administrative interface to active database
   logging
   ls-groups            List groups visible to the caller
   ls-members           List the members of a given group
   ls-projects          List projects visible to the caller
   ls-user-refs         List refs visible to a specific user
   plugin
   query                Query the change database
   receive-pack         Standard Git server side command for client side git push
   rename-group         Rename an account group
   review               Apply reviews to one or more patch sets
   set-account          Change an account's settings
   set-members          Modify members of specific group or number of groups
   set-project          Change a project's settings
   set-project-parent   Change the project permissions are inherited from
   set-reviewers        Add or remove reviewers on a change
   show-caches          Display current cache statistics
   show-connections     Display active client SSH connections
   show-queue           Display the background work queues
   stream-events        Monitor events occurring in real time
   test-submit
   version              Display gerrit version

See 'gerrit COMMAND --help' for more information.
```

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions to resolve this issue? Thanks.
(P.S:  I used 'localhost' to shadow the real ip address for privacy.)

Comment: I think the address should be `ssh://user@localhost:29418/sample-project.git`

Comment: @1615903 This is the same as `ssh://user@localhost:29418/sample-project`

Comment: @user2369034 can you use IP address instead of localhost? sure that something is wrong with the host

Comment: @HiB Okay, but I thought that was not the root cause because that in this sample I used 'localhost' to shadow the real ip address for privacy.

Answer (score 0):

try `git ls-remote ssh://user@localhost:29418/sample-project` I think without a good repo folder you will get the same error. also with wrong port. try ls-remote with a public repo first which you have access and working.. so I think somehow you are using wrong host address..

Comment: I already tried it, but it didn't work for me :( Any good suggestions???

Comment: @derekjhyang is the gerrit server placed in the same local network where you trying to connect from? are you using the local network IP to connect or some public IP?

Answer (score 0):

I think your port **29418** is not open. Please check in firewall

Comment: I've already checked my firewall, but I think anything is okay. http://pastebin.com/2TqusEnU

Comment: Have you tried git bash or Linux system just to verify ?

Comment: I've tried git-bash on my Windows desktop, but it still didn't work ! Moreover, the tricky thing was that I could do git clone from gerrit (via SSH protocol), it worked !

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved my problem.  My solution was that using the older version of "git-bash for windows (32-bit version)" instead of the latest version (64-bit, 2.10.2). For example, I used the version 1.8.x, and it worked for me.  https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/tags?after=v1.9.0